# Configurable Swatches Thumbnails not showing

Tags: thumbnails, magento-1.9, product

I am using `configurable swatches` for a product. I want to configure just like the given link.

[Click to see the product](http://www.onlinecarpets.co.uk/belton-feltback-twist-carpet.html)

But in my case the `thumbnails` are not showing. Every `associated product` have single image. and i have also upload images to the main `configurable product`. the `thumbnails` are showing, but when i give `label` name to images, then `thumbnails` are not showing..
I want the `thumbnails`, and when click on `thumbnail`, it change the `color` in drop down.. 
Any Idea.?

Comment: I had a similar problem in a project I did and could never get to the bottom of what was going wrong. I think it has something to do with the way images are linked and found a bug report with a few others experiencing the same problem which I can't find any more.  In the end I used an extension called Color Picker for Configurable products by Orange35, worked decently enough.

Comment: Thanks.. I checked the extension, but i want all the images in view more..